# How to programmatically load a Spring webflow flow and get its content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I need to load an existing Spring-webflow flow programmatically in JAVA to check it's secured tag.

My goal is to check the secured tag after specific events.

Spring-webflow 2.4 is used here. My flow looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
ns0:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">


<secured attributes="RIGHT_1,RIGHT_2" />

<view-state id="someViewState">
[...]
</view-state>

[...]

</flow>
```

So how can I get this flows "contents" via spring API? I've tried to find my way through the Classes of org.springframework.webflow.config package, but I don't find the needle in the hay. I don't even manage to load a flow successfully.

I worked with flows for some time, but I never needed to access them within Java Code.

Thx, for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by myself:

in a Class that extends org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController, you can do this:

```
// get the application Context
ApplicationContext context = getApplicationContext();
// get webflowController, must be configured in your webflowConfig file
FlowController controller = (FlowController)context.getBean("flowController");
FlowExecutorImpl flowExecutorImpl = (FlowExecutorImpl)controller.getFlowExecutor();
FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl flowDefinitionRegistryImpl = (FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl)flowExecutorImpl.getDefinitionLocator();

// flowId is the id of the flow you want to check
FlowDefinition flowDefinition = flowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinition(flowId);

MutableAttributeMap<Object> attributes = flowDefinition.getAttributes();

// finally the SecurityRule Object that you can pass to a specific AccessDecisionManager
SecurityRule securityRule = (SecurityRule)attributes.get("secured");
```

Comment: you could use a FlowExecutionListener